# position of requestAnimationFrame in the loop draw

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

```
function draw1() {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw1);
    //
    ....draw something....
    //
}

function draw2() {
    //
    ....draw something....
    //
    requestAnimationFrame(draw2);
}
```

Sometimes i see version1, sometimes version2,
so my question is :

Which draw1 or draw2 is the best and why ? thanks.

edit : may be it does not matter

Comment: really doesn't matter at all, for the same reason that it wouldn't matter with a `setTimeout`. You're just queuing a function that will be run in a future cycle of the event loop. This talk from JSConf.Asia 2018 does a really good job of explaining IMHO: [Jake Archibald: In The Loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0)

Comment: @david : ok  I have already watched this lecture, but I should see it again.
So why the specifiers did not do a requestanimationframe (callback) function, where the callback would implicitly contain the recursive call?

Comment: You mean like the equivalent of `setInterval`? Maybe they'll add it someday, I dunno. But you can always do it with the explicit recursive call.